# Restricting pointermove interactions to two layers in openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, dom-events, openlayers-3

In openlayers version v3.6 running in Chrome on Ubuntu

I have create a map with several layers (foo, bar, beltch) in it using the syntax:

```
layers:[foo,bar,beltch],
```

I would like to limit interactions to the layers foo and bar
The api documents at http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html
suggest using the following syntax

```
var selectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
    layers:[foo,bar]
 });
```

But I seem to get events for all layers, I have checked the examples and nothing seem to cover this area unless I have overlooked something.

Does anybody have any suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `filter` instead of `layers`. And make sure you set a layer property to compare later.

```
var layerFeatures = new ol.layer.Vector({
    name: 'selectable',
    source: sourceFeatures
});

var hoverInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
    filter: function(feature, layer){
        if(layer.get('name') === 'selectable')
            return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a perfect solution :-)  But the token does not have to be called 'name', it can be called anything

Comment: Yes, for sure, any property.